# var/run/docker.sock permissions problem on my EC2 instance

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have installed docker and jenkins on my EC2 instance. However, every time I restart my server I have to run the following command:

```
chmod 666 var/run/docker.sock
```

How can I keep the permissions on `var/run/docker.sock` file between instance restarts ?

Comment: Why do you need to run this command ? Those permissions are handled by the docker deamon itself and you are not supposed to mess with them. Which user are you using to run docker  commands ? Did you add that user to the `docker` group (i.e. `usermod -a -G docker yourUser`) ?

Answer (score 0):

## Do you really need to do this ?

Following my comment above. You should not run this kind of commands manually and let the daemon manage the socket file permissions on its own.

Moreover this probably indicates that you get permission errors when running docker commands as a normal user. The best practice to solve this is to add the relevant users to the `docker` group so that they can access the daemon

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker myUser
```

## If you still really need to change socket perms.

That being said, there is a direct answer to your exact question and it is possible to change the socket permissions the daemon will use at start.

The solution below is for a daemon managed with `systemd` (adapt to your specific init system if you use a different one). **Warning: such permissions will allow any users on the system to communicate with the docker daemon**

1. create a directory for custom docker socket config for systemd

   ```
   sudo mkdir /etc/systemd/system/docker.socker.d
   ```
2. create a conf file in that dir with custom socket mode

   ```
   cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/docker.socker.d/socketPerms.conf
   > [Socket]
   > SocketMode=0666
   > EOF
   ```
3. reload the systemctl daemon to catch configuration changes

   ```
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   ```
4. restart the docker service

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart docker.service
   ```